# Decimal precision positioning in browser

Tags: css, browser, css-position

Is it possible to position elements with sub-pixel positioning?

Our application builds a web-preview of PDFs but because the browser will not let us position things with fractional positions/dimensions there are rounding errors causing the web preview to look different than the PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: Browsers have their own subpixel rendering, some work well, some don't.

Comment: Using a browser for pre-press functions is a bad idea.

Comment: You're screwed. Different browsers do it differently, but they all turn the numbers into integers.

Comment: May I suggest using the Scribd API to embed the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

"Sub-pixel" support is certainly not consistent across all browsers. I personally wouldn't trust it.

I'd recommend this resource: http://elasticss.com/determination-of-algorithms-used-for-percentage-based-rounding-divs-on-browsers-and-css-frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using relative units, like Percents and Em. Pixel positionning can be tricky if you don't have the same resolution as the client, and it can't have fractionnal values.